# Creating Blazor Date Picker Component - Prevent Space Bar showing standard date Picker

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am making a date component in Blazor Server. This component is based on a Input Date field and will be used as a replacement for the standard HTML datepicker. The reason for doing this is that I need to be able to restrict the available days in the same way an old Jquery UI control would (i.e. only allow Sundays to be picked).

I have built the component and it works beautifully on the whole. The only issue that remains is when the inputdate field has focus and the spacebar is pressed the standard date picker is shown. I have managed to hide it using CSS for onclick.

Can anyone help me prevent spacebar showing the control? I tried this event on the InputDate:

```
@onkeydown="KeyHandler"  @onkeydown:preventDefault 

 private void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Key == "space")
    {
    }
 }
```

I found this approach in [MS Blazor Event Handling Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#prevent-default-actions) but when I attempt to implement it the onkeydown shows an error

> The component parameter 'onkeydown' is used two or more times for this
> component. Parameters must be unique (case-insensitive). The component
> parameter 'onkeydown' is generated by the '@onkeydown:preventDefault'
> directive attribute.

I don't even know if this is going to resolve the issue as I would need to somehow halt propagation in the key handler method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.